# How to create a dataframe in R from xml, keep getting error cannot coerce class "xml_nodeset" to a data.frame

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I am trying to extract attributes from an XML but when I try to put them into a dataframe I keep getting errors. I want to use the 'windDirection' and 'windSpeed' data and to have the corresponding 'from' and 'to' time and date stamp that correspond with measurement of wind direction and speed.

```r
library(xml2)

as_list(wind_data <- read_xml("https://metwdb-openaccess.ichec.ie/metno-wdb2ts/locationforecast?lat=51.6547167;long=-9.7734153"))

# Wind direction
direction <- wind_data %>% xml_find_all("//windDirection")
direction %>% xml_attr("deg") %>% as.numeric()

# Wind speed
speed <- wind_data %>% xml_find_all("//windSpeed")
speed %>% xml_attr("mps") %>% as.numeric()

# to and from 
time <- wind_data %>% xml_find_all("//time")
time %>% xml_attr("from") %>% as.character()
time %>% xml_attr("to") %>% as.character()

wind_data <- data.frame(direction, speed, time)
```

I have also tried:

```r
library(XML)
wind_data <- xmlToDataFrame(time, direction, speed)
```

But I get the following error:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘xmlToDataFrame’ for signature ‘"xml_nodeset", "xml_nodeset", "xml_nodeset", "missing", "missing"’

I am very new to using XML formats so I could easily be missing something very simple here but I can't seem to find the answer! Any help or pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: Don't mix packages. XML is fundamentally different than xml2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the converted results are not stored in a new variable.
Also looking the xml file, One needs to reduce the number of time values in half since there two time nodes for each forecast.

```r
library(xml2)

as_list(wind_data <- read_xml("https://metwdb-openaccess.ichec.ie/metno-wdb2ts/locationforecast?lat=51.6547167;long=-9.7734153"))

# Wind direction and update data
direction <- wind_data %>% xml_find_all("//windDirection")
direction <- direction %>% xml_attr("deg") %>% as.numeric()

# Wind speed and update data
speed <- wind_data %>% xml_find_all("//windSpeed")
speed <-speed %>% xml_attr("mps") %>% as.numeric()

# to and from 
time <- wind_data %>% xml_find_all("//time")
#there are 2 time for each speed and direction
timereduced <- time[ as.logical((1:length(time))%%2) ]
from <- timereduced %>% xml_attr("from") 
to <- timereduced %>% xml_attr("to") 

results <- data.frame(direction, speed, from, to)
```

Based on Parfait's recommendation:

```
timenodes <- wind_data %>% xml_find_all(".//time[not(location/precipitation)]")

from <- timenodes %>% xml_attr("from") 
to <- timenodes %>% xml_attr("to") 
direction <- timenodes %>% xml_find_all("//windDirection") %>% xml_attr("deg") %>% as.numeric()
speed <- timenodes %>% xml_find_first(".//windSpeed") %>% xml_attr("mps") %>% as.numeric()

results <- data.frame(direction, speed, from, to)
```

Comment: Try parsing time nodes without precipitation descendant: `xml_find_all("//time[not(location/precipitation)]")`